# PHP multiple file download

Tags: php, file, header, download

I've seen this example on the [`documentation for PHP readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

How can you **make it so It download multiple files** say `monkey.gif` and `girraffe.jpg`

**Preferably without** `ZIP` **files...**

Comment: One HTTP Request, one file...

Comment: Ever seen such a download anywhere?

Comment: Related / Possible Duplicate: [Download Multiple files in one HTTP request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332329/download-multiple-files-in-one-http-request)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.  It's not a PHP limitation, it's an HTTP/Web-Browser limitation.  HTTP doesn't provide a mechanism for sending multiple files over one request.

You could, however, have some PHP script that generates multiple iframes, which would initiate one download each, and fake it that way.

Answer (score 3):

the whole method seems a bit pointless as a physical file actually exists on the server. just use JavaScript to open all the file urls, if you have set the header correctly in your .htaccess file then the files will just download.

I would do something like this

```
<script>
    var files = ['filename1.jpg', 'filename2.jpg'];
    for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.download = "download";
        a.href = 'http://www.example.com/path_to/images/' + files[i];
        a.click();
    };
</script>
```