# creating multiple csv files from php loop

Tags: php, loops, csv

Im trying to create a loop that when executed it created multiple csv files and downloads them. This is my code:

```
session_start();
require '../connect.php'; //connect.php has connection info for my database
// and uses the variable $connect

$sqldept     = "SELECT department_name from department;";
$departments = mysqli_query($connect, $sqldept);

while ($department = mysqli_fetch_array($departments)) {
    $department = $department[0];
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=summary-' . $department . '.csv');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
    header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

    $date  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-28 days" . date("Y-m-d")));
    $edate = date("Y-m-d");

    $startdate  = "(time.dateadded BETWEEN '$date' AND '$edate') AND";
    $department = " and department_name = '$department'";
    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output     = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // output the column headings
    $sql2 = "SELECT time.id as timeid, time.staff_id, SUM(time.timein), COUNT(NULLIF(time.reasonforabsence,'')) AS count_reasonforabsence, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(NULLIF(time.reasonforabsence,''),' ', date_format(time.dateadded, '%d-%m-%Y'),' ')) AS reasonforabsence, time.dateadded,  staff.id AS staffid, department.id AS departmentid, department.department_name, staff.staff_name, staff.department_id, SUM(staff.workhoursperday), staff.payrollnum FROM time, staff, department WHERE $startdate staff.id = time.staff_id AND staff.department_id = department.id $department $staffsearch GROUP BY staff.id ORDER BY `time`.`dateadded` ASC;";



    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    fputcsv($output, array(
        'Payroll Number',
        'Name',
        'Department',
        'Hours Worked',
        'Days Absent',
        'Overtime',
        'Reasons for Absence'
    ));
    $rows = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);

    while ($rowcsv = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
        $reasonforabsence = $rowcsv['reasonforabsence'];
        //$reasonforabsence = explode( ',', $rowcsv['reasonforabsence'] );

        $overtime = 0;
        if (empty($rowcsv['SUM(time.timein)']) == true) {
            $rowcsv['SUM(time.timein)'] = 0;
        }
        ;
        if ($rowcsv['SUM(time.timein)'] > $rowcsv['SUM(staff.workhoursperday)']) {

            $overtime = $rowcsv['SUM(time.timein)'] - $rowcsv['SUM(staff.workhoursperday)'];
        }
        ;

        fputcsv($output, array(
            $rowcsv['payrollnum'],
            $rowcsv['staff_name'],
            $rowcsv['department_name'],
            $rowcsv['SUM(time.timein)'],
            $rowcsv['count_reasonforabsence'],
            $overtime,
            $reasonforabsence
        ));
    };
    readfile("php://output");
    fclose($output);
};
```

Currently the loop created 1 CSV with a new header and the department details below it like this[image]

I want the loop to create a new CSV for each department but its just not working for me. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to change name output for each  ? like output1, output2 ?

Comment: Do you mean the name of the file or the name of the ` $output` variable?

Comment: The name of the file =)

Comment: I kind of did that but instead of incrementing the numbers I appended the name of each department on the filename but unfortunately it only outputs 1 file with a random department name like: summary-A-Hull.csv

Comment: Okay so try to create zip file like suggest @Michael Kunst ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, 1 PHP Request results in one file, and there isn't really a way around this. You can, however, try to download them all as a ZIP file. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php) f.e.

Comment: The Zip files look like a good option. When you say that 1 request = 1 file. does that mean i would have to make multiple requests to get what I was i.e. multiple page loads (which isn't a good idea as the browser may think the page is failing)

Comment: or is it possible to request the data through an ajax loop for each dept. I know its a different route though.

Comment: An ajax loop for each dept. would definitely be an option. For the part `1 request = 1 file` take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663127/php-multiple-file-download

Comment: I see. Ill give the ajax option a shot and see what happens then try the zip file. thanks for you help :D

Answer (score 0):

The below are some workaround ideas, which might be useful in certain scenarios (and might be dangerous in other scenarios). ***Use under your own risk!***

#### Workaround A: Loop by redirect

1. Output a single file normally
2. Do a redirect to same url that's creating the CSV file in step#1, but append a GET flag to that, like http://www.example.net/output_csv?i=1
3. Make sure to add a loop-breaker in step#1, like `if($i==10) { exit; }`

#### Workaround B: Loop by cronjob

1. Output a single file normally
2. Make 2nd file output be handled by a separate cronjob call.
3. Make sure to add a loop-breaker in step#1, like `if($mycron==10) { exit; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this by for loop.

However, You can make a php file which can do your purpose.

```
 <a onclick="getcsv()" href="php_file_location.php?table_name=test"> Download </a>

 <script>
                                            
     function getcsv() {
                 window.open(php_file_location);
             }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem as mentioned. But in my case I was not trying to download multiple CSVs but I was uploading it to sFTP server. While creating the file instead of using

```
$output     = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

I used

```
$output     = fopen($path_and_name, 'w');
```

where $path_and_name = $path_to_sftp_folder.'/'.$file_name;
after the execution the correct file was uploaded to there respective folders correctly the way I wanted it to be. But yes the wrong file was also downloaded with same issue as sent above.

So if you are looking for uploading files on a server it can be done(even if they all have same name).