# headers dynamically read in foreach loop php

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I have a one foreach loop to download pdf files once in first time header was read and download file after that another pdf file not download?can you please help

```
foreach($file_names as $key)
{
    $fileeename=$fileenames.'.pdf';
    $dl_file = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})",'',$fileeename);
    $dl_file = filter_var($dl_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $fullPath = $path.$dl_file;

    if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r"))
    {
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-control: private");

        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            echo $buffer;
        }
    }

    fclose ($fd);   
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663127/php-multiple-file-download

Answer (score 0):

> Loop doesn't wait for PDF download process, that why you need to call function inside the loop, because loop is waiting for function process end.

```
function downloadFile(){

            $fileeename=$fileenames.'.pdf';
            $dl_file = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})",'',$fileeename);
            $dl_file = filter_var($dl_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $fullPath = $path.$dl_file;
            if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r"))
            {
                    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
                    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
                    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

                    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
                    header("Content-length: $fsize");
                    header("Cache-control: private");
                    while(!feof($fd)) {
                        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
                        echo $buffer;
                    }
            }
            fclose ($fd);
        } 

    foreach($file_names as $key){
             downloadFile();
    }
```