# Cannot get two xml file downloaded at the same time (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I am working with xml files and I would like to download multiple xml file which comes in an array. Each array contains two xml files, payments and invoices but it looks like only the first xml file ( invoices ) gets downloaded.

```
public function download(){
        $this->load->model('invoice_page');
        $data= $this->invoice_page->getCollectionTable();
        $data= json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
        foreach($data as $data1){


        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        $fileName = date("Y-m-d").'invoice_xml.xml';
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
        echo $data1['invoice_xml']; 

        $fileName2 = date("Y-m-d").'payment_xml.xml';
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName2.'"');

        echo $data1['payment_xml'];
        }
    }
```

Data1 contains two xml strings, in its array and I need to get them two downloaded with the current date with some random numbers.

Comment: `exit();` You know what it means, right?

Comment: @u_mulder Yea i know, I was just trying whatever came to my head, but I removed it from here, dint make sense.

Comment: You __cannot__ download two files one after another in a single script.

Comment: @u_mulder but then this two files are in a single row in the database, and the return array might have 100 arrays with two file string in them. Got any idea how to do it?

Comment: It would be easier to get the front end to make 2 requests using something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663127/php-multiple-file-download

Answer (score 0):

You can't force to download multiple file in same script. I think better way to handle is to archive xml files in to zip [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) and force to download zip file instead of xml.

You can do something like

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($data1['invoice_xml']);
$dom->save('file1.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($data1['payment_xml']);
$dom->save('file2.xml');

$files = array('file1.xml', 'file2.xml');
$zipname = 'filetodownload.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
exit;
```

Comment: Thats a good idea! Do you have any codes already that I can just copy paste and test?

Comment: does this help you ?