# Download a folder in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to offer the ability for users to download a folder containing multiple executable, unzipped. A good portion of my users are not used to unzip or work with zip file. I want to make it as simple as it is possible. (My .exe's are not that big)

I was wondering if I can download a folder directly in PHP securely.
Or should I direct me to the FTP option ?

Comment: Check [Download Multiple files in one HTTP request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332329/download-multiple-files-in-one-http-request). Basically it's only possible with firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to create a  [Self-Extracting Zip File](http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_zip2exe.htm) including all the exe's inside:

> To create a self-extracting Zip file from the currently open Zip file:
>
> ```
> Using the WinZip Ribbon, click Self-Extracting EXE in the Tools tab.
> Using the Legacy Toolbar, use the Make .Exe File entry in the Actions menu.
> ```
>
> Self-extracting Zip files have an extension of .EXE and can be run as
>   commands. When a self-extracting Zip file is run, the files in the Zip
>   file are automatically extracted. This is convenient because the end
>   user does not need an unzip program (such as WinZip) to extract files
>   from these self-extracting Zip files.

You can also use [winrar](http://www.win-rar.com/download.html) or [7z](http://www.7-zip.org/) to create self extracting zip/rar files.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send one file per response. That means if I send you a request, you can only allow me to download one file. Sending multiple files at once doesn't work across browsers and thus isn't reliable.

Maybe one thing you could do would be to have a list of files and tell your users to click on all of them in turn. One other thing you could do would be to have better instructions on handling zip files; nowadays Windows just allows you to double-click on a zip file and see its contents.