# How to download saved image into table in yii

Tags: php, yii

I used mulitple upload file widget of yii.

```
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',
                    array(
                     'model'=>$model,
                     'attribute' => 'Image',
                     'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png|doc|docx|pdf',
                     'denied'=>'Only jpg,doc,docx,pdf and txt are allowed', 
                     'max'=>4,
                     'remove'=>'[x]',
                     'duplicate'=>'Already Selected',
                      )
                    );
```

If i upload more than one document then it will look like this in table as well as listing and view page.

```
14461933290_14459232190_Tax-21300173.pdf,14461933291_Tax-21300173.pdf
```

Name stored into table and pdf stored into folder of project.
I provide download link into view page for download document.

```
array('label'=>'image',
                        'type'=>'html',
                        'value'=>CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->image), "http://localhost/avproject/test1/index.php/pin/downloadImage/".$model->id, array("target"=>"_blank")) 
                     ),
```

how to download this multiple uploaded pdf doument. when i upload single document then it will work properly but more than one document then it will not download proper image.

Comment: So you want to download more than one file in same request?

Comment: yes, if i up multiple image or pdf then how to download that pdf , because it save into table by comma seperated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't download multiple files using same request. Here's good answer to your question [Download Multiple files in one HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332329/download-multiple-files-in-one-http-reques).